# What options do I have missing a hand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In Pathfinder, I am playing a 11th level Oracle/1st level vigilante who primarily uses a heavy crossbow with Crossbow Mastery. All crossbows require two hands to reload even Repeating Crossbows, which I am not proficient with. We are playing with the Critical Hit Deck and a major NPC got the severed hand card on me.  So now I have no right hand. What are my options?

Comment: Your game is running on houseruled elements, and we cannot answer the question since we do not know those houserules. If your GM introduces new elements like extra-special critical hits, limb-loss, and crossbow nerfs, it is up to them to define and explain how those elements work and interact with the rest of the game, including how they can be remedied or worked around. If your GM does not wish to put in that effort, they should not introduce these elements. If they do anyway, you might consider whether this is a game you want to continue playing.

Comment: What are you taking about? House rule element? We're playing standard Pathfinder with standard Pathfinder rules with an official Paizo Pathfinder Critical Hit Deck. It sounds like hit you are the one who doesn't know what you are talking about.

Comment: What are your options... for what, exactly? Wielding the weapon effectively? Reloading it? Replacing the severed hand? Playing a functional character in general?

Comment: Your question is getting flagged as too broad. I don't have much to suggest but maybe you could narrow it down to "what feats allow me to still use a crossbow" or "what multiclass options..." instead of just a broad-sweeping "what options?"

Comment: @J.Puckett Despite being Paizo-published, the Critical Hit Deck is not an official part of the Pathfinder rules, and the rest of the system does not recognize it or account for it. It cannot be used without adjusting the rest of the system to account for it, which Paizo has not done, and a given table that wishes to use it therefore must. My apologies that you have gotten the impression that this product is something that the rest of Pathfinder is prepared for and built around, but it is not. If that seems like an incomplete product to you, well, I don’t disagree.

Comment: @KRyan What crossbow nerfs? "[Y]ou must fire [a repeating crossbow] with two hands in order to use the reloading lever [that advances the next bolt from the case], and you must use two hands to load a new case of bolts" into a [repeating crossbow.](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/crossbow-repeating/)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I misread that line as saying that you needed two hands to even use the repeating functionality within one case, but rereading that doesn’t seem like what was meant.

Comment: To be more useful, [this question about a sword + pistol character might be relevant to you, since it discusses reloading with your other hand unavailable](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77446/4563).

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111090/8610). (Just as an aside, there's at least one official way a PC can lose *both* hands: successfully destroying the [*runewarded gauntlets*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/minor-artifacts/runewarded-gauntlets-minor-artifact/).)

Comment: @V2Blast is correct. The site *can* answer *How can my PC reattach his severed hand?* and *If a PC loses a hand, what replacements are available?* and *How can my PC continue to use a crossbow despite having lost a hand?* and even *Is my PC's loss of a hand an issue over which I should leave a campaign?* But, yeah, the site can't answer *Since my PC has no right hand, what are my options?*

Comment: This site makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: Just edit the question's last sentence to say what you mean. That's all it takes. You know perfectly well what you mean there, but readers don't. (And, seriously, I know how obtuse the site can seem, but clarity in questions is really important. Folks want to help you, but right now they can't because they don't know what they're supposed to be helping you with.)

Answer (score 1):

Your only official option to replace the hand would be to find someone to cast the [Regenerate](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/regenerate/) spell on you, assuming you still have the hand. The other methods of gaining a regeneration effect all seem to only fix limbs severed while already under the effects of the items - namely a [Ring of Regeneration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-regeneration/) or a [Trollblood Elixir](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/trollblood-elixir/).

You could also potentially replace the entire arm with a [Necrograft](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necrograft/).

If replacing or regrowing the arm isn't an option, then...you are probably limited to using retraining to replace whatever crossbow-related features your character might have, or retiring the character.

Comment: Then there is also the question of wielding a weapon or casting spells. Only one hand and most spells require somatic components, so wielding a weapon doesn't seem feasible unless I take still spell, but then I wouldn't be able to cast all of my shields thay way because of the level increase to the spell, not to mention the casting time increase as well.

Comment: @J.Puckett Employing a shield as a *primary* weapon seems the best bet then. Plop the shield on the *handless* arm and bash with it to keep the hand free for casting.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan What makes you think a character can employ a shield without using a hand? I'm not aware of any rules about that, and IRL experience tells me most shields require a hand to use by default. Also, bucklers can be held in a hand without stopping spellcasting...

Comment: O, yeah, I agree that IRL a shield totally needs a hand! However, [Ready or Drop a Shield](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Ready-or-Drop-a-Shield) says, "Strapping a shield *to your arm to gain its shield bonus to your AC*, or unstrapping and dropping a shield so you can use your shield hand for another purpose, requires a move action" (emphasis mine). I dunno if that's enough also to use a shield *as a weapon*, but it's a step in that direction.